# FTIR quantitative methods to analyse / quantify changes in chemical bonds using R / Matlab

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, chemometrics

What quantitative method could I use to detect whether the radiation of sample significantly affect the chemical bond? Spectra is measured for radiated and non radiated chemical bonds and within certain wavenumber interval there are visible changes, but I would like to know what quantitative methods can I use to detect whether the changes in chemical bond is significant?

Comment: Consider if this belongs on https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/   ?

Comment: Do you mean *significant* in the statistical sense or in its everyday sense? I.e. is there a reason why you have to perform hypothesis testing or is a result including an estimate of its uncertainty acceptable or even preferred?

Answer (score 1):

With *method* I assume you mean the data analysis approach rather than the complete analytical method (since the title suggests that the measurement method is fixed already to FTIR).

A typical multivariate approach to quantify changes in the spectra would be based on Partial Least Squares (PLS) regression.

---

Wrt. to significance, both in the statistical and in the everyday sense: that will very much depend on the experimental design you employed.

- the experimental design has implications wrt. what conclusions you can or cannot draw, and
- whether certain more powerful approaches in the data analysis (e.g. paired analysis) are valid or not.

What designs are suitable in turn depends on your analytical task.